# Small issue in javascript logic

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrayobject

I have an array object as

```
var data.responseText=[{"_id":"xyz","stat":"true"},{"_id":"xyz","stat":"true"},
{"_id":"xyz","stat":"false"}]
```

I need check in this array object if there is any array with "stat":"false".If it finds I will console that.If not I will make that array to null.
One more thing this whole is in one fuction and how can I call this function after a timer of 2mins.

```
function getdata(){
return $.ajax({
type:"GET",
url:"url"**
});
}//how to call this function after 2 mins
var data.responseText=getdata;
//after getting that data how can I search for that above mentioned
```

Can someone help
!!

Comment: Check my answer .. it has both the timmeout (you can change the 3000 ms to 120000ms for 2 minutes). .. and also the test for false and setting to "null"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` to get an array where the stat value is false. `filter` will return a new array. Check the length of the array. If it is more than 0 then there is a `stat`
 whose value is false, else there is no such key with that value

```
var responseText = [{
  "_id": "xyz",
  "stat": "true"
}, {
  "_id": "xyz",
  "stat": "true"
}, {
  "_id": "xyz",
  "stat": "false"
}]

var haveFalse = (responseText).filter(function(item,index){
   return item['stat'] === 'false'


})
console.log(haveFalse.length)
```

If you have not defined `data` then `var data.responseText` will throw an error

Comment: Giving type error
Uncaught TypeError: responseText.filter is not a function

Comment: what is your variable name? responseText is what I have defined.

Comment: I have my json array in var a = data.responseText;

Comment: data.responseText is not a valid variable. If you use dot(.) that will thrown an error

Comment: Im getting data.responseText from one ajax call..Then iam storing in variable a and iam using a.filter but iam getting same error

Comment: can you please share the response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138316/discussion-between-user7350714-and-brk).

Answer (score 0):

Below are both included , one is the Timer for 3 seconds as a reference, and the other for the check for false and changing all othe elements to null. Build both these logics into your code to achieve the goal , in case of further doubt, please comment

```js
var responseText=[{"_id":"xyz","stat":"true"},{"_id":"abc","stat":"true"},
{"_id":"def","stat":"false"}];

setTimeout(function(){
$(responseText).each(function(x,y){
if(y["stat"]=="false"){
console.log(y);
}else{
responseText[x]=null;
}
}); console.log(responseText);},3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is not working exactly ? later you can set `data.responseText = responseText`